# Does any body know where can I find older versions of TCDF?

Tags: tcpdf

Does any body know where can I find older versions of TCDF , I need like a version 4... because I'm using version 3 and is faulty.

Comment: hello, welcome to stackoverflow, please read this and edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the latest version (v6) here: https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF Why use a very old version?

Edit:
You can find all versions of TCPDF here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/OldFiles/

Comment: because we have a bug and if we update to v6 or v5 we have to refactor.